# flutter giving error in displaying contact

Tags: flutter, dart, contacts

I was working with contacts in flutter so first I try to print the contacts in flutter and it was printing contact in console in the fine way. but when I try to show the contacts in the screen so it was giving error that "The argument type 'Contact' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'"
the code using for getting contacts

```
List<Contact> contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false);
```

List the contact save in

```
List<Contact>? Allcontacts;
```

main body where error it was giving

```
 body: (Allcontacts == null) ? Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  ):ListView.builder(
    itemCount: Allcontacts?.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ListTile(
        title: Text("sffd"),
      );
    },
  )
```

Comment: Are you printing contacts or Allcontacts in console in a fine way ? Could you please show how did you get value of Allcontacts variable

Comment: Allcontacts is the list i which I am saving the contacts from the function because function does not give the variable globally so I setstate the contact to Allcontacts

Comment: Okay, are you able to print value of Allcontacts in console without any error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean to display them in the title of the ListTile you should write:

```
ListTile(
 title: Text(Allcontacts[index].toString()),
);
```

or if you have a field in Contact Class that have the name of the contact and it is of type String:

```
ListTile(
 title: Text(Allcontacts[index].name),
);
```